Install drf-api-key in django
I am trying to install drf-api-key in django. I am using Linux Mint 21.3. But I am getting below error.
python3 -m pip install drf-api-key

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement drf-api-key (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for drf-api-key


What is your python version?

Wrong package name, use djangorestframework-api-key

There isn't any package named drf-api-key on PyPi. What we have are packages with similar names such as drf-api-key-auth, djangorestframework-api-key, etc. It could be that you're looking for one of these packages. If not, kindly share a link to the package you're trying to install.
